# init javascript object with array property with child objects

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to initialize a javascript object with an array of child objects in one line?  How can I do the following in just on initialization line.

```
var obj = {doc: 100,
           defaultrateid: 32,
           rates: [],
          };
obj.rates[31] = {rate: 101.00, name: "Rate 1"};
obj.rates[32] = {rate: 121.00, name: "Rate 2"};
```

Basically what I want is a single javascript object that has my user parameters.  This object will be reused on multiple web forms.  In the case of 'rates', the forms will have a dropdown to select a rate.  The web forms have client side calculations that require the matching rate object based on the rate's unique id (e.g. 32).

I'm trying to use a associative array instead of having to do looping for finding a match based on unique value.

Comment: Do you mean you actually want it all to fit on one line, or do you just want to initialize the entire object with one statement?

Comment: I want to initialize the object with one statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems a bit hacky:

```
obj = {
    doc: 100,
    defaultrateid: 32,
    rates: (new Array(30)).concat([{
        rate: 101.00,
        name: "Rate 1"
    }, {
        rate: 121.00,
        name: "Rate 2"
    }])
};
```

---

### EDIT:

Maybe you don't really need an array, you can use an object like this:

```
obj = {
    doc: 100,
    defaultrateid: 32,
    rates: {
        "31": {
            rate: 101.00,
            name: "Rate 1"
        },
        "32": {
            rate: 121.00,
            name: "Rate 2"
        }
    }
};
```

And you can still get the rates like `obj.rates[31]`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```js
var obj = {
  doc: 100,
  defaultrateid: 32,
  rates: [{
    rate: 101.00
  }, {
    rate: 121.00
  }],
};

alert(obj.rates[1].rate);
```

Comment: `var obj = {doc: 100, defaultrateid: 32, rates: [{rate: 101.00}, {rate: 121.00} ], };` would be one line

Comment: This was my first thought, but OP is creating elements `[31]` and `[32]` of the array, not just `[0]` and `[1]` as in your example. I'm not sure ATM how to do that myself, just wanted to point it out though.

Comment: Thanks for response.  I updated my original question to help clarify.  I need to find a 'rate' based on a unique id, which is why I am using an associative array.